# Error Signing Windows Phone XAP file -> SignTool Error: This file format cannot be signed because it is not recognized

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, sign, xap

I've just got my certificate to sign Windows Phone Apps and when I try to run this command:

```
XapSignTool.exe sign /v C:\Temp\MyApp_Release_AnyCPU.xap
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express.

I get an strange behavior:

The following certificate was selected:
    Issued to: XXXXXX
    Issued by: Symantec Enterprise Mobile CA for Microsoft
    Expires:   XXXXXX
    SHA1 hash: XXXXX
Done Adding Additional Store
Successfully signed: C:\Users\Fernando\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7E47.tmp\MyApp.dll
Number of files successfully Signed: 1
Number of warnings: 0
Number of errors: 0

The following certificate was selected:
    Issued to: XXXXXX
    Issued by: Symantec Enterprise Mobile CA for Microsoft
    Expires:   XXXXXX
    SHA1 hash: XXXXXX
Done Adding Additional Store
Number of files successfully Signed: 0
Number of warnings: 0
Number of errors: 1

SignTool Error: This file format cannot be signed because it is not recognized.
SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to sign: C:\Users\Fernando\Ap
pData\Local\Temp\tmp7E48.tmp\MyApp_Release_AnyCPU.xap

XapSignTool Error: signtool.exe failed with exit code 1.

Timers:
Main:528.4ms
ExtractZip(C:\Temp\MyApp_Release_AnyCPU.xap):198.5ms
Signing PE files:120.4ms
LaunchSignTool(C:\Users\Fernando\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7E47.tmp\MyApp.dll):
93.0ms
CreateXap(C:\Temp\MyApp_Release_AnyCPU.xap):107.5ms
Signing XAP file:-63524687248290.1ms
LaunchSignTool(C:\Users\Fernando\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7E48.tmp\MyApp_Release_AnyCPU.xap):56.0ms

CleanUp:6.2ms

Can anyone help me? Sounds weird to me...

Comment: maybe an unrelated question, but why do you want to sign the xap?

Comment: I'm developing a Company Hub to deliver WP apps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I was trying to use signtool.exe from x64 folder. Using the one from x86 folder works ok!

Comment: Please mark your own answer as the correct answer in order to let other SO users know the question has been answerd.

Comment: I have to wait until tomorrow to do so... thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, F.D.F Dev is right, with x86 folder works...

I had the same problem (error 1 with signtool.exe) when trying to sign a 8.1 xap file. In my case, I made it also work with x64 folder by updating Microsoft Silverlight to last version (from 5.1.20513.0 to 5.1.30514.0)

Comment: I have no idea why this works, but it did! Thank you very much! Last day and a half were lost to fault finding this.

Answer (score 1):

I had this working before. After one of the Visual Studio 2015 updates I started getting this error.

I was already using the x86 version of the signing tool.

Installed the latest version of Silverlight from Microsoft:
https://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/

And magic it was working. Not sure why.

I got this answer from the following blog:
http://www.gep13.co.uk/blog/strange-error-when-signing-xap-file-for-windows-phone-8-1-silverlight-application/

Hope this helps.

Comment: We also see this error if somebody doesn't have silverlight installed at all... or maybe some ops script is removing silverlight from all computers on your network. :(

Comment: @msp OPS is right on removing it. Silverlight still gives me the chills :(