# Is it possible to add digital signature on a hta file?

Tags: windows, digital-signature, hta, signtool

I tried to digitally sign a hta file with signtool.exe but I got following error:

```
Done Adding Additional Store  
SignTool Error: This file format cannot be signed because it is not recognized.  
SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to sign:  
C:\test.hta

Number of errors: 1
```

How can I digitally sign a hta file?

Comment: Sounds like the answer is no.

Comment: Related (no mention of HTAs) - [Can I digitally sign JScript (.js) or VBScript (.vbs) files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34445527)

Comment: Not the same file type but maybe give this a try? - [Error Signing Windows Phone XAP file -> SignTool Error: This file format cannot be signed because it is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20973573)

Comment: To be honest the `SignTool` should be able to sign most file formats, at the end of the day an HTA file is just an HTML text file. The above link suggests it might be because it's using the incorrect architecture version (x64, x86) of the SignTool.

Comment: I installed the latest version of silverlight(5.1.50918.0) and tried both signtool.exe under x64 and x86 folders but I still got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you are out the luck as it appears that Microsoft's [SignTool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz(v=vs.110).aspx) does not support the signing of HTA files. Have not been able to find anything that explicitly say's it's not supported but in my experience if you receive a message saying:

```
This file format cannot be signed because it is not recognized
```

Chances are it isn't supported.

---

- [Can I digitally sign JScript (.js) or VBScript (.vbs) files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34445527/692942)
- [Unknown Publisher warning on downloaded HTA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27841138/unknown-publisher-warning-on-downloaded-hta#comment44086467_27841138)

Comment: Do you know any other tool which supports to the signing of HTA files?

Comment: Would a Content Security Policy change the trust level?